# receivedTurnEventForMatch fails to trigger

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

I'm working on a turn based game in Swift. The game uses a GKLocalPlayerListener to know when the other person has done their turn. The method `player(player: GKPlayer, receivedTurnEventForMatch match: GKTurnBasedMatch, didBecomeActive: Bool)` does fire when the user chooses a match from the standard GameCenter screen but when they're already in a match and the other person does this turn, the method does not fire until they go back into GameCenter and choose the same match again. Is it supposed to or should I be polling?

Edit: 
i also don't get push notifications for match requests etc, but they do show up in GameCenter and in my app

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452098/gamecenter-ios-9-gamecenter-gklocalplayerlistener-methods-not-called, I've documented all the conditions I've found that cause `receivedTurnEventForMatch` to fire (as well as the rest of the game center delegates)

Comment: I am also seeing this behavior. I can sometimes get a turn based game to play a few rounds, but then the listener stops getting its protocol methods called. What can cause GameCenter to stop sending calls to a listener. (Yes, I did check, the listener is still registered.)