# How to use GKSavedGameListener protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gamekit

I am implementing online gameplay for my small turn-based iOS app. I am having some trouble implementing the "GKSavedGameListener" protocol because I am not sure how to register an object as a listener (or set an object as a delegate).

I was having similar trouble with "GKLocalPlayerListener", but found GKLocalPlayer allowed registration via "registerListener:". I found apple's documentation on this kind of lacking. Unfortunately, it does not look like "GKSavedGameListener" is as easy to implement.

I see that GKLocalPlayer conforms to "GKSavedGameListener", but does not seem to implement the optional functions in the protocol (at least I don't see them in GKLocalPlayer.h).

I am specifically interested in "player:didModifySavedGame:".

How can I implement custom behavior in the "GKSavedGameListener" protocol functions?

Answer (score 1):

Per guidance in Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gklocalplayerlistener?changes=_7&language=objc, `GKLocalPlayerListener` inherits from, among other things, `GKSavedGameListener`. You only need implement for `GKLocalPlayerListener` and you get messages for all four.

After you register, configure your class to conform to `GKLocalPlayerListener` so that your class receives those:

```
@interface MyGameKitHelperClass : UIViewController
<
    GKLocalPlayerListener 
>
```

You can then implement the functions in your class which are called when your class receives the appropriate message.

```
-(void)player:(GKPlayer *)player didModifySavedGame:(GKSavedGame *)savedGame
{

}


-(void)player:(GKPlayer *)player hasConflictingSavedGames:(NSArray *)savedGames
{

}

// or whichever functions you're interested in.
```

Comment: Thanks! I did some testing and got it to work - but found it unreliable. So I implemented my own polling function to determine when the turn had moved.

It looks like alot of people are having trouble with this protocol. [A different question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645092/how-is-gkturnbasedmatchmaker-used/47852400#47852400)