# GKTurnBasedEventListener method not called when using custom interface

Tags: swift, game-center, gamekit

According to the documentation, I should implement the `GKTurnBasedEventListener` protocol's `player(_:receivedTurnEventFor:didBecomeActive:)` method to receive turn-based event information.

Although it's documented as `GKTurnBasedEventListener`, Apple now recommends that we implement the `GKLocalPlayerListener` protocol instead of several separate protocols including `GKTurnBasedEventListener`.

From the docs:

> Adopt the GKLocalPlayerListener protocol to handle a variety of Game Center events instead of the individual GKChallengeListener, GKInviteEventListener, GKSavedGameListener, and GKTurnBasedEventListener protocols.
> Then implement the player(_:receivedTurnEventFor:didBecomeActive:) and other GKTurnBasedEventListener protocol methods to handle turn-based events that occur throughout a match.

So, I've implemented `GKLocalPlayerListener`.

At first, I was using the default Game Center interface -- and `player(_:receivedTurnEventFor:didBecomeActive:)` was called as expected (when the user started a new match, for example).

However, now that I'm using my own custom interface, the method is no longer called, *ever*. It's not called on the Simulator, and it's not called on device.

So, here's what I'm doing:

1. Set up the `GKLocalPlayerListener` protocol:

```
class GameCenterMatches: UIViewController, GKLocalPlayerListener {
    ...
}
```

2. Add the `player(_:receivedTurnEventFor:didBecomeActive:)` method to the class:

```
func player(_ player: GKPlayer, receivedTurnEventFor match: GKTurnBasedMatch, didBecomeActive: Bool) {
    ...
}
```

3. Immediately after authenticating with Game Center, register the class with the local player *(`GameCenterAuth.player` is `GKLocalPlayer.local`, and `SceneDelegate.gameCenterMatches` is `GameCenterMatches()`)*:

```
GameCenterAuth.player.register(SceneDelegate.gameCenterMatches)
```

As an example of something I believe should trigger `player(_:receivedTurnEventFor:didBecomeActive:)`, here's how I'm creating new matches:

```
let request = GKMatchRequest()
//Configure the request

GKTurnBasedMatch.find(for: request) { match, error in
    ...
}
```

**Question: Why isn't `player(_:receivedTurnEventFor:didBecomeActive:)` being called for my custom interface events, and how can I make it work?**

Comment: you'll find that lots of things in gamekit and game center are implemented in a mysterious way and don't always reflect the documentation. here are two things to try: (1) in your `GKTurnBasedMatch.find` completion closure, inspect who is `currentParticipant` and have them call `gkTurnBasedMatch.endTurn` to explicitly end the turn. (2) call `gkTurnBasedMatch.sendReminder` immediately after ending a turn. i found that in several cases network events won't push to recipient unless you follow it up w/ a reminder

Comment: also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452098/gamecenter-ios-9-gamecenter-gklocalplayerlistener-methods-not-called) is old but i found it useful, including this [linked project](https://github.com/mhatzitaskos/TurnBasedSkeleton)